# Closure of an open set in arbitrary space

Tags: general-topology

Is there any topology in which the closure of SOME (not for all) open sets (except trivial case) is itself this set? I know that in the decreate space it is true for ALL open sets.

If not then what property does guarantee this (that there are not such spaces)?

Comment: The whole space is both open and closed.

Comment: You should read the topolgical definition of "disconnected / connected space".

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks! But I am not interested in trivial case.  I change my question. Sorry for this

Comment: As @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC suggested, read [the wiki page on connected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).

Comment: Seriously, you have stumbled on to the exact condition that has become the formal definition used for "connectedness". That's pretty darn good. 

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I just heard about it. If this has some connection with my question then I will read about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topological space $X$ is said to be connected if the only subsets that is simultaneously closed and open are the whole space $X$ and the empty set $\phi$.

You see that a set is closed if and only if it's closure equals itself. So an open set whose closure(which is a closed set) is itself must be both open and closed.

So in a connected space, such non-trivial subsets cannot exist.

You only need look for non-connected spaces to find easy examples where this does happen.

For example consider $X=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ with the subspace topology induced from $\Bbb{R}$.

Here $[0,1]$ is closed(trivial to see). But it is also open as $[0,1]=(-1,\frac{3}{2})\cap X$. Thus it is also open by definition of open sets in the subspace topology.

You can now create more and more examples . Like two disjoint circles . Or even non-trivial one's like the Cantor set . Or you can put topologies on $\Bbb{R}$ like the lower limit topology called the Sorgenfrey Line. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308942/mathbb-r-l-is-not-connected) for instance.

Comment: Thanks! I think I grasp the idea. It is like the topology $\{\{A,B,CD\}, \emptyset, \{A\}, \{B,C, D\}\}$ on the set $\{A,B,C,D\}$.

Comment: Yeah that would work too.